# How to convert a document from article to report?

Tags: article, report

Is there another way of doing this besides doing a manual find "section"/ replace all with "chapter" (and the same for subsections, subsubsections etc.) ?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a unix script that gives you the option to shift things outward (i.e. for article to report) or inward (report to article, or beamer).

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then
        echo "need input file name, 0 (out) or 1 (in) " >&2
        exit 1
fi
# strips .tex from filename to append _out.tex or _in.tex
input="$1"
filename=${input%.*x}

# 0 shifts all headings outward (section->chapter, etc)
# 1 shifts all headings outward (chapter->section)
if [ $2 -eq 0 ]
then
        newfile="$filename""_out.tex"
        sed -e 's/\\section{/\\chapter{/g' \
            -e 's/\\subsection{/\\section{/g' \
            -e 's/\\subsubsection{/\\subsection{/g' \
            -e 's/\\paragraph{/\\subsubsection{/g' \
            -e 's/\\subparagraph{/\\paragraph{/g' \
            "$1" > $newfile

         echo "Saved as $newfile"
elif [ $2 -eq 1 ]
then
        newfile="$filename""_in.tex"
        sed -e 's/\\paragraph{/\\subparagraph{/g' \
            -e 's/\\subsubsection{/\\paragraph{/g' \
            -e 's/\\subsection{/\\subsubsection{/g' \
            -e 's/\\section{/\\subsection{/g' \
            -e 's/\\chapter{/\\section{/g' \
            -e 's/Chapter /\\S/g' \
            -e 's/Chapters /\\S/g' \
            -e 's/chapter/section/g' \
            "$1" > $newfile

        echo "Saved as $newfile"
else
        echo "invalid direction, 0 (out) or 1 (in) " >&2
fi
```

Comment: Nice one! Please note also the `-i` switch of `sed`, for in-place replacement.

Answer (score 5):

The timing of actions is crucial if all levels must be promoted: we have to start from the lowest level up and use `\let`.

```
\let\subparagraph\paragraph
\let\paragraph\subsubsection
\let\subsubsection\subsection
\let\subsection\section
\let\section\chapter
```

Using `\renewcommand` would turn all section levels into chapters.

However this can work only for very elementary documents without cross references. A complete solution should redefine also the counters and their representation.

```
\let\thesubparagraph\theparagraph
\let\theparagraph\thesubsubsection
\let\thesubsubsection\thesubsection
\let\thesubsection\thesection
\let\thesection\thechapter

\makeatletter
\let\c@subparagraph\c@paragraph
\let\c@paragraph\c@subsubsection
\let\c@subsubsection\c@subsection
\let\c@subsection\c@section
\let\c@section\c@chapter
\let\p@subparagraph\p@paragraph
\let\p@paragraph\p@subsubsection
\let\p@subsubsection\p@subsection
\let\p@subsection\p@section
\let\p@section\p@chapter
\let\cl@subparagraph\cl@paragraph
\let\cl@paragraph\cl@subsubsection
\let\cl@subsubsection\cl@subsection
\let\cl@subsection\cl@section
\let\cl@section\cl@chapter
\makeatother
```

Comment: But is that the correct thing to do? I know this works, but it does not 'feel right'. I would much favor replacements done in an editor.

Comment: No, it isn't the "correct" way to do it. Also all the related macros have to be changed.

Comment: @Taco I've supplemented the macros; using a "find and replace" starting from `\section` downward would certainly be better.

Comment: @egreg there is a small typo I cannot edit: `\let\theparagraph\the\subsubsection` should be `\let\theparagraph\thesubsubsection`

Comment: If I wanted to convert chapters to sections (and so on), what order would I need to do this in? I've tried simply switching the order of the arguments, along with reversing the orders within each chunk of commands, but neither have worked...

Comment: @ankushg You also have to go top-down, so starting from `\let\chapter\section`

Comment: I have done that. Right now I'm going top down, and I've tried both the order in your original post, and the reverse (`cl@` then `p@` then `c@`then `the`, and then finally just `\let\chapter\section`). I end up with a lot of complaints about missing and extra `\endcsname`s with the IEEEtran template

Comment: @ankushg I'd suggest doing search and replace

Comment: Yeah normally I'd do that too -- the problem is that I'm trying to reuse chapters from my thesis as sections for another document, and want to make changes that are reflected in both docs :-\

Comment: @ankushg The best thing is to ask a new question, with some more details about the task.

Answer (score 4):

I might be a bit overkill, but I would use `sed` for that instead of pure TeX.

Comment: Every good editor sports a "find and replace all" feature. One has only to be careful and start from the top: `\section` to `\chapter`, then `\subsection` to `\section` and so on. Also with `sed` multiple passes are needed.

Comment: Using Texlipse, I ended up doing this as well.

Answer (score 2):

Besides replacing/redefining the sectioning commands as noted in the other answers, one thing to remember is also updating the reference descriptions when using `\ref`. If your text reads

```
As seen in Section \ref{sec:first}, ...
```

after conversion to a report it should become

```
As seen in Chapter \ref{sec:first}, ...
```

If you consistently use the [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package's `\cref` command, this is a non-issue:

```
As seen in \cref{sec:first}, ...
```

The command infers the type of the reference from the label and places a textual description in front of the actual section/chapter number. I really see no reason *not* to use this package.